# Oracle SQL: Select *, statement problem (vs SQL Server)

Tags: sql, oracle

In SQL Server, I can write some code with `select *` statement, but it returns an error when writing in Oracle.

Here is an example - let's say I got a table `Order` which contains these columns:

`[Date] | [Order_ID] | [Amt] | [Salesman]`

In SQL Server, I can write code like this :

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    CASE WHEN [Amt] >= 0 THEN [Order_ID] END AS [Order_with_Amt] 
FROM Order
```

The result will be :

```
Date       | Order_ID | Amt | Salesman | Order_with_Amt
-----------+----------+-----+----------+---------------
01/01/2022 | A123     | 100 | Peter    | A123
01/01/2022 | A124     | 0   | Sam      | null
```

However, in Oracle, I cannot write the code as :

```
SELECT
    *, 
    CASE WHEN "Amt" >= 0 THEN "Order_ID" END AS "Order_with_Amt"   
FROM Order
```

It will throw an error :

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Any suggestion on this issue?

Comment: Well, there is no `FROM` in your example.

Comment: Which database do you use? **PL/SQL** is procedural extension to **Oracle**'s SQL (while Joel's answer suggests **PostgreSQL**, and you seem to be OK with that). Maybe you'd want to fix tags?

Comment: I am on Oracle's SQL, can I have edit my tag, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle's dialect of SQL, if you combine `*` with anything else then it has to be prefixed with the table name:

```
SELECT
    Order.*, 
    CASE WHEN "Amt" >= 0 THEN "Order_ID" END AS "Order_with_Amt"   
FROM Order
```

or if you alias the table (note there is no `AS` keyword for table aliases):

```
SELECT
    o.*, 
    CASE WHEN "Amt" >= 0 THEN "Order_ID" END AS "Order_with_Amt"   
FROM Order o
```

That is shown in the railroad diagram [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__I2126854):

[image: select list railroad diagram grom 19c select documentation]

The top branch has a plain`*` but can't be combined with anything else - there is no loop around to other options. The branches that do allow you to loop and add comma-separated terms have `.*` prefixed by a table (or view) or a table alias.

---

You are also using quoted identifiers, both for your column names and column expression aliases. It might be worth reading up on [Oracle's object name rules](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html#GUID-75337742-67FD-4EC0-985F-741C93D918DA), and seeing if you really need and want to use those.

If you create a table with a column with a quoted mixed-case name like `"Amt"` then you have to refer to it with quotes and exactly the same casing everywhere, which is a bit of a pain and easy to get wrong.

If you create it with an *unquoted* identifier like `amt` or `Amt` or `AMT` (or even quoted uppercase as `"AMT"`) then those would all be in the data dictionary in the same form and you could refer to it without quotes and with any case - `select amt`, ``` select Amt``, ``` select AMT`, etc.

---

But `order` is a reserved word, as @Joel mentioned, so if you really do (and must) have a table with that name then that *would* have to be a quoted identifier. I would strongly suggest you call it something else though, like `orders`.

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you very much for your explanation, this is want I need!!

Answer (score 2):

I see five things.

1. The two databases are **different dialects** of SQL, and so *of course* there are some features that work differently between them, even if this feature [works just fine](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6e22f13ac7caa2acc0c712c265bbea73).
2. The sample for Postgresql is using string literals instead of column names. It is comparing the string `'Amt'` to the value `0`, instead of the value from a column named `Amt`.
3. `ORDER` is a **reserved word**, and therefore you need to take extra steps when using it as a table name. For SQL Server, this is square brackets (`[Order]`). For Postgresql, [it's double quotes](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=04235e32a5d6293318f0568bd463bd15) (`"Order"`).
4. Postgresql is sometimes [case sensitive about these table names](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=0c05e6a0f992786cde1dbd325b0d77d6) (SQL Server is not; it doesn't care).
5. `SELECT *` is [poor practice in the first place](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list). I know many of us often use it as a placeholder while building a complex query, but we should always fill in real column names once the query is ready for use.

Comment: Thanks, for point two, I mean "Amt" in table, I have edited my question.